# bootstrap-select doesn't seem to load on time

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-select

Using bootstrap select, I initialize the plugin using the `selectpicker` so that I don't need to do it manually:

https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/

> Add the selectpicker class to your select elements to auto-initialize
> bootstrap-select.

In my page, this is how I load everything (and same order):

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <link href="bootstrap-4.6.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    
    <select class="selectpicker">
        <option>Mustard</option>
        <option>Ketchup</option>
        <option>Barbecue</option>
    </select>


    <script src="jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-4.6.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    <script src="myBootstrapSelectScript.js"></script>
</body>
```

Then in `myBootstrapSelectScript.js` I initialize the plugin:

The plugin does load, but it looks like that there are a few milliseconds on load where it's still not ready, because I have a jQuery selector right under the code of initialization, and I get error:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {        
    
    let buttons = $("button.btn.dropdown-toggle");
    buttons.each(function() {
        $(this).click();
    }     
});
```

The `$("button.btn.dropdown-toggle")` selector is for the button that bootstrap-select creates.

I get error "

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'click')"

But if I use setTimeOut then it works:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    let buttons = $("button.btn.dropdown-toggle");
    buttons.each(function() {
    $(this).click();
    }   
}, 2000}
```

So I tried to use the JavaScript version of the initialization and removed the `selectpicker` class, and manually initialized it in `myBootstrapSelectScript.js`:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('my_select').selectpicker();

    let buttons = $("button.btn.dropdown-toggle");
    buttons.each(function() {
        $(this).click();
    }     
});
```

But then I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
```

So it looks like something is not being loaded correctly, but why? Everything is according to the docs

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the order of your scripts initializing, can you move your Jquery / BS Select scripts into the head, leave BS on the bottom of body; right after your  input initialize the BS Select component ie:

```
<script type="text/javascript">$('#my_select').selectpicker('render');</script>
```

This should render BS Select quicker, before the page even renders; give it a try and see - in most cases components that are delayed in initialization stem from the thearchy order of the scripts on the page; I had multiple things before which failed to render on time (adding the timeout is a clever trick/workaround) but when I change my script order I've noticed a huge difference in initialization of components before the entire page loads.